# Python built-in help function throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to get help information on any of the built-in functions, it returns the following error:

Version: 3.7.4

```
>>> help(len)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hgak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_sitebuiltins.py", line 103, in __call__
    return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
    varchars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_-'
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: Is by any chance the name of the file you are running `string.py`?

Comment: Or is there any other file named `string.py` in the folder.

Comment: Yes, I removed that file and its working fine now. Thank you Tomerikoo and Ekrem Dincel